# How to Configure cisco router using POWERSHELL SSH.net?

Tags: powershell, router, configure, ssh.net

Good, this is the code I'm using:

```
function escribe_log($dispositivo, $log, $comando){
$Fichero_Log = "C:\Modificacion_routers.log"
$texto = $dispositivo
    $texto >> $Fichero_Log
    $texto = $log
    $texto >> $Fichero_Log
    $texto = $comando
    $texto >> $Fichero_Log
}

##PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL##
Import-Module SSH-Sessions

$ficheroIPS = "C:\ipsdispositivos.txt"
$ficheroComandos = "c:\comandos.txt"

$dispositivos = Get-Content $ficheroIPS
$comandos = Get-Content $ficheroComandos

foreach ($dispositivo in $dispositivos) {
    New-SshSession -ComputerName $dispositivo -Username USUARIO -password PASSWORD
    foreach ($comando in $comandos) {
        $SshResults = Invoke-SshCommand -ComputerName $dispositivo -Command $comando
        escribe_log $dispositivo $SshResults $comando
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    }
    $comandos = Get-Content $ficheroComandos
}

Remove-sshSession -RemoveAll
```

Works perfectly to launch "sh" show commands, my problem is that when I launch a command automatically disconnects the session, then command is not possible to launch a "conf t" to enter configuration mode and then launch configuration commands.

Do you know if this library is possible to configure a router?
if that is not possible,
would they know me any alternative to configure the router using script?

---

SOLVED:

## FUNCTION FOR CHANGES TO SSH ROUTER/SWITCH WITH POWERSHELL

```
Function set-SSH($devices, $ssh){
    function ReadStream($reader)
    {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine();
        while ($line -ne $null)
        {
            $line
            $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        }
    }

    function WriteStream($cmd, $writer, $stream)
    {
        $writer.WriteLine($cmd)
        while ($stream.Length -eq 0)
        {
            start-sleep -milliseconds 1000
        }
    }    

    $stream = $ssh.CreateShellStream("dumb", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024)

            $reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)
            $writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
            $writer.AutoFlush = $true

            while ($stream.Length -eq 0)
            {
                start-sleep -milliseconds 500
            }
            ReadStream $reader

            foreach ($command in $commands) {

                WriteStream $command $writer $stream
                ReadStream $reader
                Write-Host $reader
                start-sleep -milliseconds 500
            }

            $stream.Dispose()
            $ssh.Disconnect()
            $ssh.Dispose()
```

}

---

There are three variables to initialize $commands, $ssh, $devices

```
    #Example of file commands.txt...
    #sh conf
    #conf t
    #int f0/1
    #description Modify via powershell
    #exit
    #exit
    #wr
    #...
    $fileCommands= ".\commands.txt"
    $commands= Get-Content $fileCommands
    #Example of file devices.csv...
    #10.10.10.10;SWITCH01
    #10.10.10.11;SWITCH02
    #10.10.10.12;SWITCH03
    #...
    $devices = Import-Csv -path ".\devices.csv" -header 'ip','hostname' -delimiter ';'
    $port = 22
    $ssh = new-object Renci.SshNet.SshClient($devices[0].ip, $port, $user, $password)
    Try{
            $ssh.Connect()
            Start-Sleep -s 1
            set-SSH $commands $ssh
    }catch{
    }
```